# How to search within a subarray in php?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

I have following array in php:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [city] => London
        [institute_count_per_city] => 10
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [city] => Leeds
        [institute_count_per_city] => 10
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [city] => Edinburgh
        [institute_count_per_city] => 10
    )

    [3] => Array
    (
        [city] => GrandTotal
        [institute_count_per_city] => 30
    )

)
```

Now, the last sub array will always have constant key=>value ([city]=>GrandTotal). I want to get the value of [institute_count_per_city] for [city]=>GrandTotal.

What is the efficient way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you say it will Always be last... Simple and quick:

```
 $GrandTotal = $array[count($array) -1]['institute_count_per_city'];
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no better way than iterating over all elements and checking if the values match.

```
$result = null;
foreach($arr as $key => $item) {
    if($item['city'] == 'GrandTotal') {
        $result = $item;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will always be the last sub array in the main array. Isn't there any function which can straight away return me the last sub array? I mean I will get the     size of main array and then get the subarray on the last index.

Comment: @RishabGarg See the answer of Silvertiger here.